# How to redirect inside a modal window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

If I open a pop up window using window.showModalDialog

Doing a

```
document.location.href=xxx
```

or

```
 window.location=xxx
```

or

```
 window.location.assign(xxx)
```

inside that window, causes a new window to be opened.

How can I do a redirect **within** a modal window? Even if it works only in IE, that would be satisfactory.

Comment: Where are you setting `window.location` from? It updates the modal for me in Chrome if I call from the modal.

Comment: So does in Firefox. It only opens in a new window when trying my demo in IE.

Comment: I need it to work in ie :(

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```