# Jquery refresh entire page with ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am trying to solve a problem that I asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694005/how-to-redirect-inside-a-modal-window-using-javascript). To solve that problem, I am trying to do a jquery ajax, where I refresh the entire page with the response html. If I try

```
 success: function (msg) { 

 $(document).html(msg);
    },
```

it throws errors.

How do I tell jquery to replace the current page with the html contents received back in the response?

Comment: Have you tried replacing body instead of document? e.g. $("body").html(msg)

Comment: Yes that causes the page to throw errors. Remember that the response is the entire page, which has its own head element.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace just the content that's changing on the page. I doubt that your header/footer are changing too. Add an ID to whatever wrapper div you have in your layout and then change your success to this:

```
success: function (msg) { 
$("#ID_YOU_ADDED_GOES_IN_HERE").html(msg);
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the response will have an element with the id ID_YOU_ADDED_GOES_IN_HERE. Then the next time I try to do a refresh again, there are two elements with the id ID_YOU_ADDED_GOES_IN_HERE.

Comment: Your response should only have the content that goes in the div, not the div itself. The other options is to replace the content instead of changing the html value. $("#ID_YOU_ADDED_GOES_IN_HERE").html(msg); would become $("#ID_YOU_ADDED_GOES_IN_HERE").replaceWith(msg); See http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$("body").html(content);
```

If the error persists, please paste the whole code because it's not possible to find the error without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Retrieve the HTML string using AJAX
2. Use [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) to create a disconnected DOM lattice to parse the HTML
3. Pull items out of the $.parseHTML return value and insert them one by one into your $("head") and $("body") elements